# Automation engine is unable to playback the test because it is not able to interact with the desktop... but desktop not locked

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have been pulling my hair out over this one for two days now.

I got a new and much faster testing box, and it has started failing consistently every time at the same place in code, and very similar locations in the test cycle.

I am running Visual Studio 2017, though that is not really relevant.  The latest TFS server, I think it is 2017 as well.  I have two test boxes with the test power shell agent, test gui agent, and test controller, installed.  One of them is really old and slow, it works great other than having timeout issues.  The newer one I am trying to migrate to is running windows 10.

The windows 10 test box is logged in as a domain user I use for testing, this user is a local admin and is the user used to install all the testing agents.  I run UltraVNC to connect to my test boxes remotely so as to avoid the issues that RDP and TeamViewer cause for the test agents.

The code will run great for 5 for six iterations, but during one specific test it always errors out on three iterations.  The iterations are usually around the same point in time, but not always using the same data.

The code in question that triggers the error is:

```
Mouse.Click(save_tab);
```

where save_tab is a UITestControl object, a hyperlink on a web page.

The error triggered is:

> Message: Automation engine is unable to playback the test because it
>   is not able to interact with the desktop. This could happen if the
>   computer running the test is locked or it’s remote session window is
>   minimized.
>
> StackTrace: at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestLogGenerator.ExceptionRecorder(Exception
>   exception, Boolean rethrow) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.ThrowIfScreenLockedOrRemoteSessionMinimized()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception
>   exception, IPlaybackContext context) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception
>   exception, String actionName, UITestControl uiControl) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestActionExecutorCore.Click(UITestControl
>   control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point
>   relativeCoordinate) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.ClickImplementation(UITestControl
>   control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point
>   relativeCoordinate) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1
>   function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent,
>   Boolean logAsAction) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(UITestControl
>   control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point
>   relativeCoordinate) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(UITestControl
>   control)

I have used VNC to actually watch the test machine as it has triggered these errors.  The screen saver never turns on ( it is disabled ), the screen never goes to sleep ( that is also disabled ).  Instead the entire test hangs for a period of time before triggering the errors.

In the catch portion of my try-cache for this error I try and take a screenshot using the testing browser object and get this error:

> Message: Parameter is not valid.
>
> StackTrace: at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc() at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY,
>   Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize,
>   CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation) at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY,
>   Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.CaptureImagePrivate()
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.b__173_0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1
>   function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent,
>   Boolean logAsAction) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.CaptureImage()
>   at Testing.Base_CodedUITest.CaptureAndSaveImage(UITestControl doc,
>   String FileName)

I then try taking a screenshot using:

```
UITestControl.Desktop.CaptureImage();
```

resulting in this error:

> Message: Parameter is not valid.
>
> StackTrace: at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height,
>   PixelFormat format) at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32
>   height) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.CaptureImagePrivate()
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.b__173_0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1
>   function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent,
>   Boolean logAsAction) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.CaptureImage()
>   at Testing.Base_CodedUITest.CaptureAndSaveImage(UITestControl doc,
>   String FileName)

It seems clear that the test is not able to communicate with the computer for some reason.  I am not sure why though.  Once this error has been handled the test continues on repeating the exact same test successfully several times in a row before triggering the same error again.

I do have one other possible clue on this issue.  When connecting to this test box running UltraVNC I will periodically get a message that the connection has been terminated by the server ( the test box ), but it will always re-connect afterwards.  I do not have this issue with my older test box.  I have tried running a constant ping test to this newer test box during one of these UltraVNC connection hiccups and did not see any reduction in speed or lost packets.  The connection across our entire lan is less than 1ms.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

EDIT: Upon recommendation I started looking through the event log.  One event stuck out to me as being odd from Source = VSTTExecution.

> (vstest.console.exe, PID 5356, Thread 9)
>   TestTypes{13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b} could not be loaded
>   because the TIP could not be instantiated for the following reason(s):
>   An item with the same key has already been added.

Source = VSTTController had this one, but do not think it is an issue since the tests are actually running.  I suspect the controller and agent software I have installed may just be old and no longer needed.

> The Controller service could not connect to Test Management Server.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading,
>   Version=15.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

And there was this one, Source = VSTTAgentProcess:

> (QTDCAgent32.exe, PID 10416, Thread 51) DataCollectionAgentProcess:
>   Parent process exited. Parent Exit Code: -1

EDIT 2:

As I try and collect more data on this I am finding this error occurring about the same time as the other ones.  I think it is just a deeper error.  Unfortunately it is also more generic, so finding anything on Google is difficult.  I am pretty sure at this point that there is a problem deep within the OS, IE, or the test engine.  My hope is to find a work around.  In a month I will be able to test on yet another piece of hardware as well.

This second error is the original error that I am trying to take a screenshot of.  I am trying to click a button.  A button that is very visible and available, there is no visible error.  For some reason the CodedUI test engine doesn't seem to recognize that IE even exists.  However, once this error is past, the test engine is able to pick the browser back up and continue on with the next page in the test.

> error level 2
>
> Message: The playback failed to find the control with the given search
>   properties. Additional Details:  TechnologyName: 'Web' ControlType:
>   'Document' TagName: 'BODY' Failed to find any control that matched the
>   search condition ControlType='Document'
>
> StackTrace: at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapControlNotFoundException(COMException
>   ex, IPlaybackContext context) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException
>   innerException, IPlaybackContext context) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception
>   exception, IPlaybackContext context) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception
>   exception, String queryId) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant(String
>   queryId, Int32 maxDepth, Int32& timeLeft) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetUITestControlRecursive(Boolean
>   useCache, Boolean alwaysSearch, ISearchArgument searchArg, IList`1
>   windowTitles, Int32& timeLeft) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetElement(Boolean
>   useCache, ISearchArgument searchArg) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.Search(ISearchArgument
>   searchArg) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindInternal()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindControlIfNecessary()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.WaitForControlReadyPrivate(Int32
>   millisecondsTimeout, Boolean doLogging) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.<>c__DisplayClass186_0.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1
>   function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent,
>   Boolean logAsAction) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.WaitForControlReady(Int32
>   millisecondsTimeout) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.WaitForControlReady()
>   at Testing.Base_CodedUITest.NavigateToUrl(String url) in
>   c:\agent_work\2\s\VerizonOTM\Other\trc_UITesting\Tests\UI\Base_CodedUITest.cs:line
>   348
>
> error level 3
>
> Message: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM
>   component.
>
> StackTrace: at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.FindAllDescendants(String
>   bstrQueryId, Object& pvarResKeys, Int32 cResKeys, Int32 nMaxDepth) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindAllScreenElement(String
>   queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean singleQueryId, Boolean throwException,
>   Boolean resetSkipStep) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindScreenElement(String
>   queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean resetSkipStep) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant(String
>   queryId, Int32 maxDepth, Int32& timeLeft)

Comment: I don't have any clue about your problem, I haven't run into this one yet. But here are some ideas that might help you out.
Do all your tests run successful on your devPC? This could rule out the test itself as source of your problems.  
Are you doing additional checks to make sure save_tab is available and reachable?  
If the test machine is the source of your problem, do you find any clues on what's going on in the windows event viewer?

Comment: Event viewer has quite a few errors in it related to testing it seems.  Test agent was not connecting, but that does not seem to affect testing, which makes me wonder if it is even necessary, it might be an older tool.

There's an error about vstest.console.exe that seems like something that might affect things, so I am going to look into that.

Comment: I tried updating VS, test agent, and test controller as that was one solution for one of those errors I saw in the logs.  But the problem still exists as do all three errors in the logs.

Comment: I am assuming that you have used descriptive ( creating reference to the control from your code rather than relying on test builder). In this case can you try playinh with your playback settings like Playback.PlaybackSettings.MatchExactHierarchy = false; or Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled or extending think time?

Comment: I have messed around with those settings, yes.  The difficult part with those is that I believe they are not actually used until CodedUI actually looks for the control.
So, for example.  I have these three lines:
Playback.PlaybackSettings.AlwaysSearchControls = true;  
this._BaseBrowser = new BaseBrowser(TestContextInstance);  
Playback.PlaybackSettings.AlwaysSearchControls = false;  
However, I think that until something actually uses the _BaseBrowser variable in such a way that the engine needs to find it, then it will not actually look for the control, and those settings will not apply

Comment: For the document body, which is what cannot be found, I create the HtmlDocument with this search setting:
            this.SearchProperties[HtmlDocument.PropertyNames.TagName] = "BODY";
and then I call this method on the resulting object, body.WaitForControlExist().
My hope is that calling that method causes CodedUI to look for the object right away, however I am not convinced that it is actually happening until later in the code.

Comment: I am now going through an exercise of upgrading TFS to 2018 from 2017 so I can get a newer test agent.  I am hoping that might make a difference.

Comment: The upgrade seems to have no affect.  Next step is to completely reformat the test machine and start from scratch.

Comment: I have fixed another issue, which may have inadvertently been triggering this one.  One of my tests downloads a file, while the file is being requested there is no indication that anything is happening at all until the file is presented by the browser for download.  I am thinking that while that download is pending certain actions with the browser becomes unavailable to the test engine.  If I just wait long enough for the file to be generated then things appear to start working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem.

The test in question that kept triggering these errors was downloading a file.  If the file took too long to be generated and presented for download then the test tried to move on and log it as a failure.  However, because it had not actually failed yet (it was just taking a long time) the browser was still busy and unavailable for CodedUI to interact with.

During the download process the browser gave no indication that a file was being downloaded.  It looked like it was available for use in screen shots, coded ui was detecting it as available, the DOM said it was ready to go.  And there was no page change that I could look for because the page was not actually changing.

The way my test was structured, I was on one page of my site, I dynamically built the URL to download the file, and tried to navigate to that URL.  This would result in one of two things happening: either the file would error out and the site would actually navigate to that URL, or the file would be presented for download.

So my solution ended up being to set a very long timeout (10 minutes) and just keep looping through checking to see if the URL was still the same and if a file had been presented for download yet.  This allowed me to wait even for the files that were taking longer to download.  And once the browser had actually finished with the download request it became available for CodedUI again and my tests were able to continue on.

Comment: If you haven't already, make sure you use a while loop in combination with that time-out so that your test continues as soon as the download is finished. You could possibly save some minutes that way.

Comment: Yes, I use the codedUI wait for a minute inside of a loop that runs 10 times.  So it keeps on checking things so I can continue as soon as the file is available.

Comment: A minute is quite a long time in computer terms, specially if this test is part of a large set of tests or is run several times. While the Coded UI test is running the computer should not have much else to do so it might be better to have a much smaller time out and run the loop more times. Be careful of the overall timeouts for individual tests and for the test run. See the `Test timeouts` section of the ".testsettings" file.

Comment: Agreed, a minute is a long time. That is the upper bound of time given to CodedUI to wait for the download object to appear.  If it appears sooner then it will continue on sooner. I put it inside of a loop because CodedUI has not proven itself to be very stable, so if CodedUI itself has a problem or hangs, then I give it a minute to fix itself before the next iteration of the loop where I give it another shot. I have a lot of little hacks like that in my code because CodedUI seems to blow up over just about everything. I think calling it something other than a beta product is being too nice.

Comment: Some of my tests do take a very long time to get through all of the tasks I have them doing and I have had to increase the defaults for them, my longest is set to 2 hours.  I do not use the traditional Microsoft data driven testing capabilities.  I have found that rolling my own data driven capabilities in this area is far more maintainable; their system is simply no where near flexible enough for what I am doing.

Comment: Jereme, you should really try a `Stopwatch` in combination with a while loop. Try something like `while(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 600 && FileAvailable == false){//set FileAvailable here after checking things}`. So your loop will continue for 10 minutes or stop iterating as soon as the ´FileAvailable´ boolean has been set to ´true´. When I started implementing this, it greatly speeded up my tests.

Comment: That would work as well.  What I currently have is `while (iterations_left > 0) { iterations_left--; if(file.WaitForControlExist(5000)) break;`